# Angular 2 Directive ngAfterViewInit called multiple times

Tags: angular2-directives

I have a hard time finding out why ngAfterViewInit is called 4 times for a directive.
 Can anyone let me know the reason? I am new to Angular 2.

Here is the code snippet:

```
  import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, AfterViewInit }from '@angular/core' @Directive({
selector: "[hightlightBaseOnName]" }) export class HightlightBaseOnName implements AfterViewInit  {

@Input() data1: any = null;

@Input() data2: any = null;

private dom: any = null;

constructor(
    private _element: ElementRef
) {
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.data1);
    console.log(this.data2);        
}
```

}

Comment: I'm guessing it's instantiated for each element that the directive selector matches? Ie do you have 4 elements that match the selector `[hightlightBaseOnName]` on the page?